# My 3d scan to low poly bake is coming out broken with artifacts

Tags: rendering, texture-baking, baking

[image]

I converted down from about 500,000 poly to 30,000 poly and used instantmesh to retopologize the mesh.

Anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Looks like decimation process ruined your UV map.

Comment: The original that I baked from has not had a decimate modifier applied